# How do I go about simplifying $1-\frac{\sin^2x\tan x}{\tan x+1}-\frac{\cos^2x}{\tan x+1}$ to $\sin x\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

> This is a tricky trig problem I'm stuck with. The problem is asking me to simplify $$1-\frac{\sin^2x\tan x}{\tan x+1}-\frac{\cos^2x}{\tan x+1}$$
>   to $\sin x\cos x$.

What I've been doing so far is trying to remove those $tan$ functions.
$$1-\left(\frac{\sin^2x\tan x-\cos^2}{\tan x+1}\right)$$
$$1-\left(\frac{\frac{\sin^3x-\cos^3x}{\cos x}}{\tan x+1}\right)$$
$$1-\left(\frac{\frac{\sin^3x-\cos^3x}{\cos x}}{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+1}\right)$$
I made this complicated. Is there a simple way to do this problem?

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \sin x gives $\sin x$ instead of sin x which gives $sin x$

Comment: Noted! Still learning how to use the MathJax syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$1-\frac{\sin^2x\tan x}{\tan x+1}-\frac{\cos^2x}{\tan x+1} =1-\frac{\sin^2x\tan x+\cos^2 x}{\tan x+1}=1-\frac{\sin^3x+\cos^3 x}{\sin x + \cos x}=\\=\frac{\sin x(1-\sin^2x)+\cos x(1-\cos^2 x)}{\sin x + \cos x}=\frac{\sin x\cos^2x+\cos x\sin^2 x}{\sin x + \cos x}=\sin x \cos x$$

Comment: I am confused with the last part of your working. Did you use another identity?

Comment: Sorry I skip a step, that is $$\frac{\sin x\cos^2x+\cos x\sin^2 x}{\sin x + \cos x}=\frac{\sin x \cos x(\cos x+\sin x)}{\sin x + \cos x}=\sin x \cos x$$

Comment: Oh! I see! What tips can you give for tackling such trig problems?

Comment: Try to learn the way to obtain and proof all the main trigonometric identities and do a lot of exercises on that! Do not try to memorize all the expressions but try to understand them and check them by simple cases. That's always a good reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities Bye!

Comment: Noted! I guess practice makes perfect. Thanks again

Comment: @AugieJavax98 Yes of course, that's the old way which still works! For any doubts you can Always ask for some hint here to the community! See you!

Answer (score 3):

You dropped a sign in the first line.  The $\cos^2 x$ term should be positive inside the parentheses.  Now multiply the numerator and denominator by $\cos x$ and you have a sum of cubes in the numerator.  The denominator cancels.

Comment: The signs always get the best of me.

Comment: Thanks for the hint